# PInvoke and char**

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, char, marshalling

I got this assembly from someone which I'd like to use in my c# application.

The header looks like this:

```
int __declspec(dllimport) s2o(WCHAR* filename, char** out, int* len);
```

I managed to get it partly working, using:

```
[DllImport("s2o.dll", EntryPoint = "?skn2obj@@YAHPA_WPAPADPAH@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int s2o(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string filename,
    ref char[] @out,
    ref int len
);
```

And then calling it like this:

```
char[] result = null;
int length = 0;
s2o("filepath", ref result, ref length);
```

It seems to work partly, because 'length' actually gets a value.
Unfortunatly, 'result' stays null.

What should I do to get this working?

**Edit:**

Ok I managed to get to to work by replacing the char[] with a IntPtr and then calling 'Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi' like Nick suggested:

```
string result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
```

However, because of the comments in that same answer I'm a little worried about memory usage. There are no other methods provided in the assembly so how can I clear things up?

Comment: You could try to replace _char[]_ with _IntPtr_ and call _PtrToStringAuto_ for the pointer: _Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(@out)_

Comment: Please declare your function in your DLL with extern "C" to disable name mangling. Now to your question. We can't tell you how to call this function until you tell us how the `out` parameter works. Who allocates what? Do you have any documentation for `s2o`?

Comment: @David: I think he's saying it's a 3rd party DLL so he probably can't add extern "C".

Comment: It is indeed a 3rd party dll.

Comment: You could try using either the Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem or FreeHGlobal. But without knowing how the memory is allocated in the DLL it's hard to know what's going to happen!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx) Method.

Or as *Centro* says in the comment to your question, PtrToStringAuto may be more appropriate.

> Copies all characters up to the first
>   null character from an unmanaged ANSI
>   string to a managed String, and widens
>   each ANSI character to Unicode.

Also note that you may be responsible for freeing the memory returned from this function.

Comment: How would the managed code free memory allocated in the native code?  That could only work if the native code provided a method to free it, exported the allocator, or used the COM allocator.

Comment: @David: Yes, you're right. The O.P. would need to look at the docs for the DLL and work out how the memory is expected to be freed.

Comment: While PtrToStringAuto works, i don't get the expected result (instead I get lots of chinese characters), so I think something is going wrong. Also, I'm fairly sure 'out' is a char array, so wouldn't I need to do some sort of conversion first?

Comment: Did you try the Ansi version?

Answer (score 6):

About your last question:

- `char` is a single character.
- `char*` is a pointer to a char. If this is interpreted as a string, all data in the memory that follow this memory address will be seen as belonging to the string, up until a value with 0x0 is encountered. Passing a `char*` into a method means, that this method can change the contents of the string, but not its length.
- `char**` is a pointer to a pointer to a char. Passing this to a method means that the method is able to create a new string and return the new address to the caller.

Comment: Another possibility is that `char**` is an array of C strings, e.g. `argv`.