# How to pass a Reference-to-Pointer between between C# and an un-managed C++ Library?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, reference

In my C/C++ Library, I've a function with such a prototype:

```
long myFunction( const wchar_t*& pszOutput)
```

The Dll allocates the memory for pszOutput and deallocates it too.

How do I call this function from C# ?

I've tried a lot of variation of the following line (with out, with MarshalAs, ...), but I always get a crash when exiting myFunction:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "myFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern long myFunction(ref string szOutput);
```

Does anyone knows, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows, C++ `long` isn't C# `long`, it is normally C# `int`. Check the `sizeof(long)` in C++. If it is 4 then it is `int`.

Try passing a `out IntPtr szOutput`, then use the `Marshal.PtrToStringUni()` with the returned `IntPtr`.

See for example [PInvoke and char**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5975380/613130) for a similar problem.

Comment: about the long in C++/C#, I've just typed a "dummy" peace of code, not the real one ;-). Thx a lot for the answer. I'd already saw the example you mentioned, but simply hoped, a "easier" solution could exist, and if possible without any copy of the returned string.