# C++ Calling using DLLImport Method Signature needed for Custom Type, File and Pointers

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, methods, dllimport

In C# with DLLImport need to call C++ custom type variable and pointers.

Custom Types:

```
 typedef unsigned char UN_Char;
 typedef enum { Valid = 0, Invalid = 1, Unknown = -999 } AppResponseCode;
```

Called in SomeAPI.C

```
 static AppResponseCode SomeFunction(UN_Char ** vUC1PtrPtr,size_t * vSize1Ptr, UN_Char * vUC2Ptr,size_t vSize2, FILE *  inputFile, char * vcharPtr)
```

Now I need to Call C++ Function from C#.

Once I tried to create Reference its failed witht the message

> A Reference to '.....\SomeApi.DLL' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is valid assembly or COM Component

So I go with other route to Import DLL  using DLLImport but here I don't have signature for the calling C++ Function

```
[DllImport("SomeAPI.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern ?AppResponseCode? SomeFunction( ?????emphasized text ) ;
```

Can someone help me to identify Function Signature ?

Comment: Most of the parameters seem to be kind of easy, however where you are going to get FILE* ? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975380/pinvoke-and-char

Comment: Can you modify the `C++` source code or is it given to you in a compiled form? Compiled C++ names are mangled (they include parameter types) and it might be easier for you to use `extern "C" { ... }` to export it as a `C` function which doesn't include parameters and can be referenced as `SomeFunction`.

Comment: When ever there is a pointer, doesn't matter simple pointer or double or anything, the signature is `IntPtr`. For the `SomeFunction` you need to export the name from the dll. There are some programs that can do that. The correct import is `[DllImport( "SomeAPI.dll",
             EntryPoint = "The exact name you get from dll",
             ExactSpelling = true,
             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
        public static extern .......`

Comment: In most times the exact name is the name + `@` symbol + the total number of bytes of the function arguments. So you have 5 pointers, assume pointer size is 4 bytes, you have 20 plus 4 for the size_t, total 24. So you get `SomeFunction@24`. You set this name to the `EntryPoint` in your `DllImport` and leave `SomeFunction` after `public static extern....`

Comment: γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε , as Lay Man to C++ , I understand you only half way, It would be easier if you could provide me the Method Signature for both call and return :  static extern  ? SomeFunction(?);   .. and if annotation need change then that's additional as you advised ..

Comment: Not Possible Zxxc , I had access to the Original C++ Code but the problem is code is Controlled and just provided for internal structure .. We must have to Call Made only from CompiledVersion i.e. DLL